# How to stop WordPress from creating native thumbnails?

Tags: post-thumbnails

Stop use thumbnail native image - one major issue,

I want Use cache image thumbnail inserted of native image, its create junk on web-space
e.g If I upload one product its make 3-6 thumbnail image from original picture.

How can I use Cache images system e.g. megento, prestashop, opencart with easy one click all cache clear option

note: use spl folder location for store cache images not wp-content/2015/12/

Answer (score 1):

Go to `wp-admin/options-media.php`

Set `width` and `height` to `0` for all sizes you do not want to have created.

Comment: Arsylum, thanks for response
I know this mehtod, please let me know

How can I use Cache images system e.g. megento, prestashop, opencart with easy one click all cache clear option

note: use spl folder location for store cache images not wp-content/2015/12/

Any Plugin???

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question. Besides that I have no first hand experience with the systems you mentioned, sorry.